# Firebase RecyclerView Adapter App is Crashing: Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui, recyclerview-layout

I am working on an Android app. I use Firebase database. But I am stuck with a problem. My app crashes when I use FirebaseUI RecyclerViewAdapter. Here are all my dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.0.1' 
 // For Phone number Auth
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1'
```

Here is my Activity Code:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FirebaseUser mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference db;
    private String uid;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.userView);
       // mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        //uid=mAuth.getUid();
        db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers,userViewHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, userViewHolder>(
                AllUsers.class,
                R.layout.add_people,
                userViewHolder.class,
                db
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(userViewHolder viewHolder, AllUsers model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public static class userViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        View mview;
        public userViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mview=itemView;
        }
        public void setName(String name){
            TextView username=(TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.addName);
            username.setText(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Modal Class:

```
public class AllUsers {
    public String Name;
    public String Status;
    public String Profile_pic;
    public AllUsers(){

    }

    public AllUsers(String name, String status, String profile_pic) {
        Name = name;
        Status = status;
        Profile_pic = profile_pic;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }

    public String getProfile_pic() {
        return Profile_pic;
    }

    public void setProfile_pic(String profile_pic) {
        Profile_pic = profile_pic;
    }
}
```

Please help me. I dont know what is my mistake. I have tried a lot of codes but all in vain. I will be very thankful to you if you help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post crash logs.

Comment: how to get crash logs?? I am new to android

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat
  will help you.

Comment: 05-24 14:07:54.760 13917-13917/com.myapper.hasee.stack I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x002c at 0x3e in Lai;.a
05-24 14:07:54.775 13917-13917/com.myapper.hasee.stack I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.

Comment: This is the last message that i found in LOGCAT.

Comment: Those are general logs. You're looking for [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) from the crash, which should be a large section of red lines.

Comment: I think you need to add Snapshot parser and FirebaseRecyclerViewOptions with the Recycler view adapter

Comment: @harshjain It looks like OP is using version 2.x of FirebaseUI, which didn't yet have `FirebaseRecyclerViewOptions`. Their constructor looks fine against that version. If they were using a newer/incompatible version, that would surface as a compile time error, not as a run time crash.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How can i solve it?? You can see my all firebase dependecies??

Comment: If you app crashed, there is a stack trace in your logcat for it. Seeing that is the most likely way someone will be able to help you.